# Convertir cadena a Array de Numpy

Tags: array, string, numpy

Estoy leyendo de un fichero información de este estilo línea a línea

```
[[[106.23706131  74.19983673  53.1510033 ]]]
[[[59.24701176 41.45938749 29.7537066 ]]]
```

Esto quiero pasarselo a otras variables, pero se leen en formato string y necesito que sean arrays de numpy. Debido a que cuando les doy uso obtengo el siguiente error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'subtract' output from dtype('<U45') to dtype('float32') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se agregaron comillas para poder emular un string, aunque no las veo en tu código, pero tú dices que estan en ese formato.

Sin bibliotecas, puede que obtengas el resultado de la siguiente forma, como un objeto tipo lista:

```
arrayPrueba = [[['106.23706131  74.19983673  53.1510033']]]
print(type(arrayPrueba))
print(len(arrayPrueba))

for i in arrayPrueba:
    print(type(i))
    for j in i:
        print(type(j))
        for k in j:
            print(type(k))
            splitResult = k.split()
            print(splitResult)

print(type(splitResult))
print("Lista:",splitResult)
```

Saludos

Comment: Probé lo de las comillas y sigue sin funcionar. Se me olvidó comentar que en la función donde extraigo esos arrays tienen el formato zeros=((1,1,3)), con lo que necesitaria pasarlos al mismo formato (creo) al leerlos del fichero. No sé si iría por ahí la cosa. De todas formas muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: De nada @xXNukem KS, puse comillas porque no había otra forma de emular el problema de mi lado, puede que verificando el tipo de objeto que recibes y  tal vez con algún método de numpy lo puedas resolver, buena suerte!.